Correlation and Multicolinearity Analysis for BigData
Pandas is very well optimized to handle the most common scenarios that we need when we preprocess or analyze data.
What about BigData, specifically BigData (1k+ columns, 100k rows) in BigQuery?

The upper triangle of the correlation matrix for 1k columns would be ~500k pairs.
VIF would take its time. If we want to drop columns iteratively, infinite.
PCA is probably a good approach - we lower interpretability
Regularization?

I want to know which techniques are suitable for handling these things for BigData, preferably keeping original columns and removing redundant data.

Hi , could you please clarify more on the issue , by giving an example in bigquery .

BigQuery is a columnar datastore. You can minimize overhead by using nested arrays to reduce rowcount and redundancy. BigQuery ML is also built on top of it and can use ML models within the query editors.
